# How to determine which thread a method will executes on when using TPL?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

I know that the *TPL is task-oriented, while the classic threading model is worker-oriented. 
Tasks let you focus primarily on what problem you want to solve instead of on the mechanics of how 
it will get done*. But I am still a bit confused when it comes to thread and task relationship.

Below is a demo code:

```
namespace AsyncUnderTheHood
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main Start : {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            AwaitTest();
            Console.WriteLine("Main End : {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void DoWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DoWork Start: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("DoWork End: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }

        public async static void AwaitTest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AwaitTest Start : {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Task t = new Task(DoWork);
            t.Start();
            await t;
            Console.WriteLine("AwaitTest Done : {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is like this:

```
Main Start : 1
AwaitTest Start : 1   <------------ A
DoWork Start: 3
Main End : 1
DoWork End: 3
AwaitTest Done : 3    <------------ B
```

**My question is, why A and B is on different thread?**

The same method is executed on different threads, will this cause issue when thread affinity is important?

Comment: You are using an async void method in a Console Application.. is that really going ok?

Comment: @WouterdeKort As you can see from the output, it does work (because of the `ReadLine()`. Though it's a bad practice and it shouldn't be done in production code.

Comment: @WouterdeKort It's "works" because of the ReadLine in main.  If the main didn't keep the application running like that, you'd never be able to "await" on the async void method and the application could exit before the task even gets started.  It's not recommended to use async void methods for anything other than event handlers.

Comment: That you are asking this question, and consequently fighting the tool instead of leveraging it, indicates that you need to rethink your design, and/or your understanding of the tool. Rethink your application as work done by (real physical) people in an offce, communciating with actual file folders of data. When that workflow makes sense, translate back to an automated solution.

Answer (score 3):

> why A and B is on different thread?

First, if your `Task`s are scheduled by the default scheduler, then there is no guarantee which `Thread` will a `Task` run on. And the parts of `AwaitTest()` are executed separately, so there is no guarantee they will run on the same thread.

Second, the default scheduler uses the `ThreadPool` to execute `Task`s. And the first part of each `async` method runs synchronously. In your case, this means the first part of `AwaitTest()` will run on the main thread and the second part will run on some `ThreadPool` thread. So, you're actually guaranteed that they *won't* run on the same thread.

> will this cause issue when thread affinity is important?

It certainly could. But it will work correctly in the most common case where thread affinity is important: GUI programming. This is because GUI applications have `SynchronizationContext` set, which means that if the first part of an `async` method runs on the UI thread, the second part will run there too (unless you disable this by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`).

But in other cases, it will cause problems. For example, take the following code:

```
Monitor.Enter(lockObject);
await someTask;
Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
```

This code wouldn't work in a console application (`Exit()` will most likely throw `SynchronizationLockException`), because the `Exit()` can run on different thread than `Enter()`.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked the system to "await" a task.  What you're really asking is that the thread that invoked `await` should continue running and everything after the `await` is a "continuation" that will get run asynchronously when the task is done.  Since there's no "message pump" in a console application, there's no easy way to marshal back to the "main" thread and thus the continuation just continues on with the asynchronous `Task`'s thread.  If you performed the same test in a WinForm or WPF application, the continuation would run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/New-And-Improved-CLR-4-Thread-Pool-Engine.aspx) has a good description of how TPL uses multiple task queues with work stealing to layer on top of the existing thread pool for optimum performance.